# Custom event not working when registered in an ASPX file

Tags: asp.net, events, user-controls, asp.net-3.5

I am trying to register a custom event I added to a user control.
I can do this in code behind, but not in the aspx file.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

The user control:

```
public delegate void MemberSelectedEventHandler(object sender, string fullMemberName);

public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public event MemberSelectedEventHandler OnMemberSelected;

    protected void Button_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (OnMemberSelected != null)
        {
            OnMemberSelected(this, "Peter");
        }
    }
}
```

This works (code behind of aspx page):

```
MyMemberControl.OnMemberSelected += new MemberSelectedEventHandler(MyMemberControl_OnMemberSelected);
```

But this doesn't (aspx page):

```
<scn:MemberControl OnMemberSelected="MemberControl_OnMemberSelected"  runat="server" ID="MyMemberControl" />
```

Answer (score 3):

In the markup you need to prefix your event property with On so the page will know to register the event. Morzel had the answer though it's not stated explicitly.

```
<scn:MemberControl OnOnMemberSelected="MemberControl_OnMemberSelected"  runat="server" ID="MyMemberControl" />
```

`OnOnMemberSelected` should cause your handler to be invoked as expected.

Comment: thanks, it saved my day 10 years later :D

Answer (score 2):

First of all I have to take a bit note: When you make a custom event, you don't need to name it with 'On' prefix. .Net framework adds this prefix and the markup intellisense will show you OnOnMemberSelected.

I don't know if it needs, but try to put the delegate declaration inside your WebUserControl1 class. I always do this.

Markup intellisense reacting really slow and I don't see if it deterministic when popullates intellisense information again.

Sum of all:
 - put the delegate definition into your class.
 - build
 - insert your markup code.

If intellisense doesn't work immediatelly I think it will works.

Comment: Please don't add your name to each post - your name is already stamped here ^^^